# Operating on individual time: HH:MM:SS

Tags: java

Given a date and time in string format like "20 10 50", I have successfully converted it into an SDF by referring the internet. Now how do I operate on the same date I just created?

`X=3600*HH+60*MM+SS`

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        int numberOfTests=3;
        String [] timeStamps=new String[3];
        timeStamps[0]="10 10 10";
        timeStamps[1]="10 10 16";
        timeStamps[2]="10 10 50";

        int [] X=new int[3];
        DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh mm ss");
        Date t1=sdf.parse(timeStamps[0]);
        Date t2=sdf.parse(timeStamps[1]);
        Date t3=sdf.parse(timeStamps[2]);

        //X=3600*HH+60*MM+SS
```

This is how far I have reached. I know what I have to do after this, I've got it all sorted, but I am getting stuck here.

I tried to do it using `split` at first, but it became complex later on, so I stuck to this method.

Comment: What is the problem with this ?

Comment: I want to take individual HH MM SS and operate on it

Comment: So call methods on the `Date` instance you created...?

Comment: I am really new and I don't know all the methods. Could you please specify the ones I have to use? ```t1.getTime()``` I have used later in the program tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to apply `X = 3600*HH + 60*MM + SS` you don't need to pass through a date (either `Date` or `LocalTime`) just use the `String`

```
for (int i = 0; i < timeStamps.length; i++) {
    String[] parts = timeStamps[i].split(" ");
    X[i] = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]) * 3600 + Integer.parseInt(parts[1]) * 60 + Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(X)); // [36610, 36616, 36650]
```

---

To see an example with a parsing, you'll see that you get the same but more costly with a parsing to `LocalTime`

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH mm ss");
for (int i = 0; i < timeStamps.length; i++) {
    LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(timeStamps[i], fmt);
    X[i] = time.getHour() * 3600 + time.getMinute() * 60 + time.getSecond();
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(X)); // [36610, 36616, 36650]
```

Comment: Later in the program, I have to operate on the Date format specifically., so I converted it before. So ```split``` is the only method around?

Comment: @NewJava yes that's if (just `parseInt` instead of `paresInt`) but you can also pass throught a Date, look my edit

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot Azro. This will help me later in the program as well! yeah that was a typo, sorry

Comment: @NewJava Note azro uses the `java.time` API instead of `java.util.Date`. Always prefer the former.